# codewarrior interrupciones

Tags: c

Estoy usando el IDE codewarrior para una CPU MC9S08JM16.

Me gustaría usar una interrupción de un botón. El ejercicio consiste en que cuando quiero darle a un boton se me active un LED. Luego tengo dos ficheros: uno el programa principal y otro el fichero de configuración de la CPU con sus interrupciones.

En el fichero principal tiene esta pinta:

```
#include "delay.h"
#include <mc9s08jm16.h>


void MCU_init(void); /* Device initialization function declaration */


void main(void) {

/*VARIABLES LOCALES*/
extern bool ON;


/* setup */
MCU_init(); 


/* loop */
for(;;)
{
    if(ON)
    {
        LedVerde = 1;
    }else{
        LedVerde = 0;
    
    espera_1s();

    } /* loop forever */
}
```

Y ahora dentro de mi fichero de la configuración tengo:

```
#include "MCUinit.h"


bool ON = false;

void MCU_init(void)
{
/* Common initialization of the write once registers */

/* SOPT1: COPT=0,STOPE=0 */
SOPT1 = 0x13U;                                      
/* SPMSC1: LVWF=0,LVWACK=0,LVWIE=0,LVDRE=1,LVDSE=1,LVDE=1,BGBE=0 */
...
...//Aqui viene toda la configuracion y es irrelevante para esta duda
...
}/*MCU_init*/


__interrupt void isrVkeyboard(void)
{
   espera_1s(); //Antirrebote

   ON = ~ON;

   KBISC_KBACK = 1; //Desactiva la bandera de la interrupcion
}
```

La duda es que no funciona correctamente la variable ON y no se como llamar esta variable.
Me da error por ejemplo si lo meto como un parámetro dentro de la función:
__interrupt void isrVkeyboard(bool ON)

o cuando lo dejo tal cuál lo describo aquí al debugguear, los valores de ON son de 0 a 255, luego cambia a 240 luego a 40.... No funciona exactamente la regla ON=~ON.
Quisiera evitar también poner variables globales porque en un código complejo, empieza a fallar el programa debido a las variables globales.

¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias

Comment: Me cambia de valor ON porque la dirección de memoria de esta variable queda pisada por otra función que tengo el programa que no tengo expuesto en el post

Comment: No puedes poner `esperar_1s()` dentro de la rutina de atención de una interrupción; tienen que ser tan rápidas como sea posible. Lee [Leer un pulsador con Arduino con interrupciones y debounce](https://www.geekfactory.mx/tutoriales/tutoriales-arduino/boton-o-pulsador-con-arduino/)

Comment: El dalay es algo temporal, lo quitaré en el futuro.

Y en cuanto a volatile, funciona igual.
La cosa es que en el main, realmtente tengo una función con un array. Lo que hace esta función es coger valores hasta completar un arrayd e 64 posiciones. (Lo que viene siendo la lectura de un sensor).
Y es que precisamente la posición de memoria ON y la posición de memoria de una de las casillas del array es la misma y cuando la función me hace su función pues me cambia el valor de ON

Comment: ¿¿ Como van a ser iguales las posiciones de memoria de variables distintas ??